# a lie algebra is semisimple if and only if it does not possess a non-zero solvable ideal?

Tags: lie-algebras, semigroups, simple-groups

I encountered a statement in *Symmetries, Lie Algebras and Representations* by Jurgen Fuchs& Christoph Schweigert (pp. 58) that

> a lie algebra is semisimple if and only if it does not possess a non-zero solvable ideal.

I find this statement a bit confusing. Consider a non-abelian lie algebra, say $g_1$, which has a proper ideal and another simple lie algebra $g_2$. Then $g=g_1\oplus g_2$ should be non-semisimple, right? According the above statement, then $g$ must possess a non-zero solvable ideal (if not then it is semisimple). Now how to construct the non-zero solvable ideal?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Oh, I mean the direct sum....,very sorry.

Comment: No, the direct sum could be still semisimple. Consider $g_1=\mathfrak{sl}(2)\oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2)$ and $g_1=\mathfrak{sl}(2)$. Then $g_1$ has the proper ideal $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, and $g_1\oplus g_2$ is still semisimple.